# AWS Codebuild Golang Lambda using Serverless Framework

Tags: go, lambda, bitbucket, serverless-framework, aws-codebuild

I'm building golang lambda functions using the serverless framework in AWS CodeBuild. This project is in a private bitbucket repository. And the CodeBuild source is the bitbucket repo

I'm having some problems of using local packages in the code.

I have this project structure

```
hello
   test
      test.go
   main.go
serverless.yml
...other files
```

what I'm trying to do is to use package `test` in `hello/test/test.go` in the `hello/main.go`.

And I've tried 2 options.

1. Import the package using "myproject/hello/test"
2. Using bitbucket url and `dep ensure`. Moving `test` to another project.

the problems:

1. in AWS CodeBuild, the package cannot be found as the real package directory is `/....aws path/bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>/` and the `$GOPATH` is `/...aws path/`.
2. dep ensure freezes when writing the private bitbucket repo. I'm assuming that it's because authentication issues?

So, what can I do to use **my** golang packages in AWS CodeBuild? And it's a private repo not a public one.

Comment: The import name for the package is "bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>/test", not "myproject/hello/test". (Maybe there's a hello in there somewhere too. Hard to tell since the names in your question are inconsistent)

Comment: Hi @Peter, yeah.. that should be it in the CodeBuild instance, but in my developer environment, it's only a folder and not starting with "bitbucket.org...". Or should I use that format in my dev environment?

Comment: Yes, you should: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: right! Ok then! If you make it as answer I'll make it as the answer! Thanks!

Comment: This question has got to be a duplicate, but apparently my search mojo left me and I can't find a good existing question.

Comment: that's why i asked this :p but if you found one, I'm happy to flag this question as a duplicate! @Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Peter's comments, I resolved the issue by using the full path of my bitbucket repo in my $GOPATH/src.

so the path should be `bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>`